# Mirror across object origin

Tags: mirror, origin

Sorry for noob question but I just wanna do this: mirror geometry in Edit Mode across my object's Origin (orange dot), not 3D cursor. All tuts are about 3D cursor and the help doc is somewhat unclear to me.
I thought I needed to set Individual Origins and then CTRL+M but it always mirrors across mass centre while my origin is distant.
[image]

Comment: In edit mode, you should be able to press CTRL+M followed by XYZ to select your axis for mirroring. By default it should mirror around your objects origin.

Comment: In my case by default it mirrors along mass centre. I made a new model, didn't tweak any settings. But what should be the Transform Pivot Point? "Individual Origins"?

Comment: Ah, yes. Actually, you need to mirror in object mode to mirror around object origin. So in object mode: CTRL+M, then XYZ to select your axis.

Comment: If you want to do it in edit mode (partial mirror for instance), use the 3d cursor: place it at the mirror point, then set the 3d cursor as pivot point and Ctrl M + axis.

Comment: I want to do it in edit mode cuz I only need to mirror part of my object. Ok, so I HAVE TO move 3D cursor? Cuz help doc that I screenshot refers to edit mode and says that I can use origin and not have to do one extra step and manipulate 3D cursor.

Comment: If I understand your case, you'll have to use the 3d cursor here, eventually placing it at the object origin if it is what you want to do.

Comment: Ok, this is what I will do. I just thought that I wouldn't have to use 3D cursor. This is what the screenshot shows: it's in edit mode and mirrors about origin, while 3D cursor is somewhere else, completely irrelevant.

Comment: The doc extract is talking about individual origins (not object origin).

Comment: I see now. I will use 3D cursor then.

Comment: But mirroring about object's origin would make sense as a feature request, don't you think?

Comment: Yes but as @Geri said, you can do that in object mode (for the whole object, though).

Comment: Sure but I would then have to separate my selection into another object. Yet another extra step. Y'know, I came here from SketchUp which really keeps simple things simple. It has a fantastic plugin which allows you to define mirroring plane by drawing 3 virtual points in model space. Very much CAD style. I wish there was such an addon for Blender!

Comment: shortcut: shift + S (Snapping menue) -> 2 (Cursor to selected); Semicolor opens the Transform pivot point menue to choose Cursor. It can be realy fast not using the ui.